# org.hibernate.exception.MappingException or ConstraintViolation

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate 4.1.9. I have Users, and the Users have a list of Accounts, and Accounts have list of Transactions. Here is my hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<class name="User" table="users">
    <id name="userId" column="userid">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="username" column="username" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="password" column="password" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="registerDate" type="timestamp" column="register_date"/>
    <list name="accounts" table="accounts" inverse="true" cascade="all">
        <key column="userid" not-null="true"/>
        <index column="accountid"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.joe.data.Account"/>
    </list>
</class>
<class name="Account" table="accounts">
    <id name="accountId" column="accountid">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="balance" type="big_decimal" column="balance"/>
    <property name="lastModified" type="timestamp" column="last_modified"/>
    <list name="txns" table="transactions" inverse="true" cascade="all">
        <key column="accountId" not-null="true"/>
        <index column="transactionId"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.joe.data.Transaction"/>
    </list>
    <many-to-one name="userId" class="User" column="userid" not-null="true" 
         unique="true" cascade="all"/> 
    <many-to-one name="accountType" class="AccountType" column="account_type" 
        not-null="true" cascade="all" unique="true" />
</class>
<class name="Transaction" table="transactions">
    <id name="transactionId" column="transactionid">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="description" column="description"/>
    <property name="amount" type="big_decimal" column="amount"/>
    <property name="dateAdded" column="date_added"/>
    <property name="reoccuring" type="numeric_boolean" column="reoccuring"/>
    <many-to-one name="category" class="Category" column="category" 
        not-null="true" cascade="all" unique="true" />
</class>

<class name="Category" table="categories">
    <id name="categoryId" column="categoryid"/>
    <property name="categoryName" column="categoryname" not-null="true"/>
</class>
<class name="AccountType" table="account_types">
    <id name="accountType" column="account_type"/>
    <property name="accountName" column="name"/>
</class>
```

If I leave inverse="true" on the list of accounts (in the User) I get the ConstraintViolationException because the userid is not getting put in the insert query. If I take inverse="true" off of the list of accounts, I get org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.joe.data.Account column: accountid (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

To clarify lowercase names are database columns names, camel case are class variable names. I know Transaction class isn't working quite right yet, but if I could get the Accounts to insert I could do the same thing to get the Transactions to insert.

**Edit:** I added the many-to-one on the Account class and now I am getting another exception where hibernate is complaining about missing a getter for userId in com.joe.data.Account

Answer (score 0):

In order to get inverse="true" work, you need to define many-to-one for User in Account and for Account in Transaction class and mappings.

Comment: I added <many-to-one name="userId" class="User" column="userid" not-null="true" unique="true" cascade="all"/> Now it says I am missing a getter for userId in Account

Comment: Your Account class should have an object of User and its corresponding accessor methods